# Adding holes to a polygon removes it's fill color

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I created a Polygon that fills an entire Google Map.

After I add a couple of holes, the map works fine. The map gets shaded with the polygon fill color and the holes gets rendered.

But, after adding a 3rd hole, the holes still display the stroke of the Polygon, but the polygon fill color becomes transparent.

My holes list size is 63 but it can vary.

Is there any limit of holes that a polygon can have? or how can I draw a polygon with multiple holes in it? all the holes are contained within the map.

EDIT 1

I can't add the exact code snippet as it is from my job, but this is something similar as what im doing.

```
fun GoogleMap.render(geoJSONS: List<JSONObject>) {
    val wholeMapPolygon = PolygonOptions().add(
        LatLng(-89.999999999999, -180.0),
        LatLng(89.99999999999, -180.0),
        LatLng(89.99999999999, 179.99999999),
        LatLng(-89.99999999999, 179.99999999),
        LatLng(-89.99999999999, 0.0)
    ).strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
     .fillColor(Color.WHITE)

    val layers = createGeoJSONLayers(this, geoJSONS)
    val holes = getPolygonsFromGeoJsonLayers()

    for(hole in holes) {
        wholeMapPolygon.addHole(hole) // Here, adding more that 3 makes the wholeMapPolygon fill color dissapear.
    }

    addPolygon(wholeMapPolygon)
}

/**
* In this function, some other functions get called to extract each list of coordinates for each layer polygon.
**/
private fun getPolygonsFromGeoJsonLayers(layers: List<GeoJsonLayer>): List<List<LatLng>> {
   val holes = mutableListOf<List<LatLng>>()
   for(layer in layers) {
      val polygonFeatures = getGeoJsonLayerPolygonFeatures()
      for(polygonFeature in polygonFeatures) {
         holes.addAll(getCoordinatesFromFeature(polygonFeature))
      }
   }
   return holes
}

private fun getGeoJsonLayerPolygonFeatures(features: List<GeoJsonFeature>): List<GeoJsonFeature> = features.filter { feature ->
   feature.geometry.geometryType == "Polygon"
}

private fun getCoordinatesFromFeature(feature: GeoJSONFeature): List<LatLng> {
    val coordinates = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
    (geometry as? GeoJsonPolygon)?.coordinates?.filter {
        it.isNotEmpty()
    }?.forEach {
        coordinates.addAll(it)
    }
    return coordinates
}

private fun createGeoJSONLayers(map: GoogleMap, data: List<JSONObject>) = data?.map { jsonObject ->
   GeoJsonLayer(map, jsonObject)
}
```

Comment: post some code and some screenshots

Comment: I can't post the exact code as it is from my company, I'll post something similar to it

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to lie in the position of your holes. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#create_a_hollow_polygon) on Polygons says the following:

> If the hole intersects the outline of the polygon, the polygon will be
>   rendered without any fill.

And the [Polygon's reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) states:

> Holes
>
> A hole must be fully contained within the outline. Multiple holes can
>   be specified, however overlapping holes are not supported.
>
> Fill Color
>
> The default value is transparent (0x00000000). If the polygon geometry
>   is not specified correctly (see above for Outline and Holes), then no
>   fill will be drawn.

Hope this helps!